# Error al instalar Angular CLI en Mac

Tags: angular, npm, terminal

espero que estén muy bien.

Quiero instalar Angular para trabajar en unos proyectos de prueba, pero al instalar el package me aparece este error:

[image: Error Angular]

¿Alguna idea de cómo solucionarlo? he visto algunos tutoriales para arreglarlo pero se meten mucho en la terminal y yo voy aprendiendo.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: ejecuta el comando como un usuario que esté incluido en los sudoers, o ejecutalo como root su -p [contraseña]

Comment: Me puedes ayudar con el comando?

Comment: @javiertxu18 ya investigué y si funcionó! Muchas gracias! Solo utilicé sudo npm install -g @angular/cli